# how to alert the result of command?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, pipe

I used this command

```
ifconfig ppp0 | tail -2 | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $3,$4}' | alert
```

to show the result of the command before the "| alert", but it shows me the command not the result, in my case the result of the command :

```
ifconfig ppp0 | tail -2 | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $3,$4}'
```

is (40.5 MB) for example.

Comment: why not `ifconfig ppp0 | egrep -o '\(.+?\) '`?

Comment: What do you mean by "it shows me the command not the result"? What is your desired outcome?

Answer (score 2):

Just give the result of your command as a parameter to `alert`:

```
alert "$( ifconfig ppp0 | tail -2 | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $3,$4}' )"
```

[update] And if you don't want the command at all, do:

```
notify-send --urgency=low "$(ifconfig ppp0 | awk 'NR==8 {print $3,$4}')"
```

Comment: Fine! Don't hesitate to chose this answer then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
rxbytes=`/sbin/ifconfig ppp0 | tail -2 | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $3,$4}'`
zenity --notification --text="$rxbytes bytes received"
```

Instead of using zenity to pop up a GUI box you can use whatever you want, or just echo out the $rxbytes variable.